# Error while running fuzzy search using pg_trgm extension

Tags: database, postgresql, fuzzy-search, pg-trgm

I have created pg_trgm extension in postgres. Application works fine for querying for several days. But after few days, gives an error **ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying % text
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit                                     type casts.**
When dropping the extension and recreating, then everything works smooth.

What goes wrong not able to get? Is there a permanent solution so that I didn't need to create the extension again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you didn't create the extension `pg_trgm` in that database, or you created it in a schema that is not on the `search_path` active for the query.

You can also schema-qualify an operator:

```
WHERE col OPERATOR(schema_name.%) 'searchstring'
```

Comment: The extension is created in database,  query also works fine. But after a few days, when trying to run fuzzy search, it gives error. When recreating the extension, everything goes smooth again. Is there a problem with the extension?

Comment: Then there must be something on your system that drops the extension, or perhaps drops and re-creates the whole database regularly. PostgreSQL does nothing of that sort by itself.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the whole database drops & re-create regularly? Also, can you provide any solution how to stop this behavior of this database if this's happening?

Comment: The database does not drop and re-create. Be assured that this has an outside cause. You can log database activity to find out more.

Comment: Thanks Launenz Albe. The above answer helped me solved the problem.